# Fetching values from database for select box

Tags: database

I have created a table named `ic_states` i want to make a select box from the database values using wpdb. I have tried wpdb::get_row but not getting the result. It is showing only value. Can someone help me. I have checked the question if anyone asked before but i didn't found any suitable query for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can used below code to get results from the database in wordpress.

```
global $wpdb, $posts;
$prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
$query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$prefix}states");
if($query){
    echo '<select><option value="select">Select</option>';
    foreach ($query as $value) {
      echo '<option value="'.$value->ID.'">'.$value->ID.'</option>';
    }
    echo "</select>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks [lalitpendhare](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/114472/lalitpendhare) it worked for me.